# Why we can use type definitions in the private part in class declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

It is considered that those definitions (members of classes, types etc) that are in the private part are data and types of the class itself.
But there are exceptions that I don't understand. 
For example, why in the example below, do the C++ language rules fail to describe the type with the keyword auto?

```
class MyClassA 
{

    class MyClassB
    {
    public:
        MyClassB::MyClassB() {};

        MyClassB::~MyClassB() {};

        void get() const {};
    };

    MyClassB m_B;

    public:

        MyClassA() {};
    ~MyClassA() {};

    const MyClassB& get()
    {
        return m_B;
    }
};

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
 {
    MyClassA classA;

    const MyClassA::MyClassB& ref1 = classA.get(); //! error C2248: 'MyClassA::MyClassB': cannot access private class declared in class 'MyClassA'

    const auto ref2 = classA.get(); //! OK, but why is it good here?

    ref1.get(); 

    return 1;
}
```

What does the С++ standard say about this?

I am developing code using MSVS2015 (toolset v140)

Comment: "[...] rules fail to describe the type with the keyword auto?" your text seems to contradict what the code is showing. It is the line without `auto` that fails, no?

Comment: but how this relates to the point of view of Object-oriented programming?
We are using type definitions out of sight. Is it normal?

Comment: think of `private` as restricting the acces for you, but the compiler of course knows also privately declared types